# unexpected required parameter 'bottom' in matplotlib.pyplot.barh()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm drawing a simple horizontal bar plot. For readability, I'd like to use 
keyword arguments, but I get an error with undocumented required parameter, when I do this.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(4,2))

# this example works
plt.barh([1, 1, 1], 
         [9.5, 8.5, 28.5], 
         [.3, .3, .3],
         [-2207, -2197, -2188])

# here I want to use keyword arguments for readability, according to 
# https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.barh.html?highlight=barh  
plt.barh(y=[1, 1, 1], 
         width= [9.5, 8.5, 28.5], 
         height = [.3, .3, .3],
         left = [-2207, -2197, -2188])

# But I get error:
#   File "<ipython-input-6-2f6ee5c89917>", line 4, in <module>
#   left = [-2207, -2197, -2188])

# TypeError: barh() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bottom'
```

There is no 'bottom' argument in the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.barh.html?highlight=barh):

````
bar(y, width, *, align='center', **kwargs)
bar(y, width, height, *, align='center', **kwargs)
bar(y, width, height, left, *, align='center', **kwargs)```
````

Comment: matplotlib version

Comment: '2.0.0'. Should I upgrade?

Comment: Yes, Latest version is 2.2.2

Comment: Upgrading really solved this, many thanks!